# node-mysql - return rows where column contains string

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I want to create a function that returns objects from DB where a string is contained in one of the object's columns.

This is my code:

```
router.get('/search-news', function (req, res) {

  var input = req.query.title; // user input
  var dynamicInput = '%'.concat(title.concat('%'));

  connection.query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE title = ?', [dynamicInput], function (err, rows) {
    console.log(err);
    res.json(rows);
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="search-news" class="form-inline right search-form" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Поиск..."></input>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Поиск"></input>
</form>
```

However, this function always returns 0 records from the DB. Where is my problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dynamic input seems to be appending percent signs to the beginning and end of the string.

```
 var dynamicInput = '%'.concat(title.concat('%'));
```

It is highly unlikely that any strings actually have this format, so I suspect you want `like`:

```
 connection.query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE title like ?', [dynamicInput], function (err, rows) {
```

However, I am not familiar with nodejs, so there may be other problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best and easiest way to do it.

```
 router.get('/search-news', function (req, res) {
    
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE title = ?', [`%${req.query.title}%`], function (err, rows) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json(rows);
      });
    })
```